# How to run application within UNNotificationContentExtension

Tags: ios, swift

I make an ios game. I need to add an advanced ios 10 notification with three actions (as *UNNotificationAction*). 
One of the actions has to run my game. I have implemented the notification, actions and *UNNotificationContentExtension* class with *didReceive* function (with *UNNotificationResponse* argument).
Everything works good: I have received my notification with actions.
What I should do in didReceive function to run my game? My code:

```
 func didReceive(_ response: UNNotificationResponse, completionHandler completion: @escaping (UNNotificationContentExtensionResponseOption) -> Void) {
    switch (response.actionIdentifier) {
    case "inGame":
        // run game here!!!
    case "sendAgain":
        // some logic
    case "cancel":
        // another some logic
    default:
        completion(.dismiss)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `activationMode` of the `inGame` action to  `UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground`. It will cause the action to open the game when user touches it.